# Magento Custom API Product Attribute Not Saving

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have created a custom API to update 4 attributes of the product out of which only 2 are updating not others.

I have already created attributes and assigned them to a product and working properly through the admin panel.

Attribute Code from Admin Panel

```
1- color
2- size
3- style
4- length
```

API Call in Postman

`http://192.168.8.107/rest/V1/mid/updateattribute/`

API attributes Data

```
{
    "data":{
        "sku":"MJ08-XS-Blue", 
        "color":"Blue",
        "size":"S",
        "style":"2",
        "length":"M"
    }
}
```

Here is the code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\UpdateAttribute\Model\Api;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Attribute
{
    protected $logger;
    
    private $_productRepository;
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function updateAttribute($data)
    {
        $response = ['success' => false];   
                
        try {
            
            $productData = $this->_productRepository->get($data['sku']);
        
            // Color attribute
            $isAttrExist = $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('color'); 
            $color_id = '';
            if ($isAttrExist && $isAttrExist->usesSource()) {
                $color_id = $isAttrExist->getSource()->getOptionId($data['color']);
                $productData->setData('color', $color_id);
                $response[] = ['success' => true, 'message' => $data['color']];
            }
            else{
                $response[] = ['success' => false, 'message' => "Color " .$data['color']. " not available"];
            }
            
            // Size attribute
            $isAttrExist = $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('size'); 
            $size_id = '';
            if ($isAttrExist && $isAttrExist->usesSource()) {
                $size_id = $isAttrExist->getSource()->getOptionId($data['size']);
                $productData->setData('size', $size_id);
                $response[] = ['success' => true, 'message' => $data['size']];
            }
            else{
                $response[] = ['success' => false, 'message' => "Size ". $data['size']. " not available"];
            }
            
            // Style attribute
            $isAttrExist = $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('style'); 
            $style_id = '';
            if ($isAttrExist && $isAttrExist->usesSource()) {
                $style_id = $isAttrExist->getSource()->getOptionId($data['style']);
                $productData->setData('Style', $style_id);
                $response[] = ['success' => true, 'message' => $data['style']];
            }
            else{
                $response[] = ['success' => false, 'message' => $data['style']." not available"];
            }
            
            // Length attribute
            $isAttrExist = $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('length'); 
            $length_id = '';
            if ($isAttrExist && $isAttrExist->usesSource()) {
                $length_id = $isAttrExist->getSource()->getOptionId($data['length']);
                $productData->setData('length', $length_id);
                $response[] = ['success' => true, 'message' => $data['length']];
            }
            else{
                $response[] = ['success' => false, 'message' => "Length " .$data['length']." not available"];           }       
            
            $productData->save($productData);
            //$objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->save($productData);
            
            $response = ['success' => true, 'message' => $data['sku']];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
        $returnArray = json_encode($response);
        return $returnArray; 
   }
}
```

Code is working for 2 attributes only

```
1- color
2- size
```

While other 2 attibutes not updating

```
3- style
4- length
```

Comment: check the attribute type of style and length, they are input text or option dropdown..?

Comment: all are dropdowns, the color attribute is using swatch also and it is also updating.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing attributes settings found that the attribute which was not updating had scope "Website" after changing the scope to "Global" it is working fine.

[image]